# Is it possible to disable index from function while inserting records into table and enable otherwise

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to disable index from oracle function while inserting records into table and enable it once insertion completed ?

Comment: No (unless you are talking about disabling or dropping the index and recreating it later).

Comment: Disabling an index depends on many things, you'll need to post your index DDL to get a good answer.

Comment: No, but you can fake it by doing clever things with partitions

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are constraints based i.e. primary key, unique key you can disable or defer these constraints until end of transaction. This should disable the indexing too.

Check out this link - 
[Deferring Constraint Checks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm)

Comment: But "Deferrable unique and primary keys must use nonunique indexes", which is very unlikely.  And if it's a primary key you can make it unusable, and set skip_unusable_indexes=true, but it still uses the index.

Comment: @jonearles Why is that unlikely? Oracle *can* use a non-unique index to enforce a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  What I meant was that it's very rare (at least in my experience) to have a non-unique index for a primary key.

Comment: @jonearles: Ah! Then I completely agree ;)